# Create a folder google drive in specific path

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

i have used the script of create a folder from this link: [Create a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#creating_a_folder)
and it's work.

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Invoices',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

How can i create the folder in specific path ?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask].  I have edited your question to show you how you should phrase your questions in the future.  Try to remember to add the code you are currently using, and describe your issues with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the fileId of the folder you want to create your new folder in as parents parameter in the metadata.

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Invoices',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    'parents': 'FOLDERID'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```